# Get all sibling elements given a specific node

Tags: python, xml

I have the following example.xml file:

```
<ParentOne>
   <SiblingOneA>This is Sibling One A</SiblingOneA>
   <SiblingTwoA>
      <ChildOneA>Value of child one A</ChildOneA>
      <ChildTwoA>Value of child two A</ChildTwoA>
      <ChildThreeA>Value of child three A</ChildThreeA>
      <ChildFourA>Value of child four A</ChildFourA>
   </SiblingTwoA>
</ParentOne>
```

I'd like to retrieve the tags and values for all sibling elements to the "ChildThreeA" node. I would like therefore for the output to be something like the below (or anything similar):

> ChildOneA = Value of Child one A
>
> ChildTwoA = Value of Child two A
>
> ChildFourA = Value of child four A

I've seen many examples similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20358691/3480297) that uses XPath, but I was hoping to use a straightforward library that can return this for me.

For example, I'm using the `getprevious().tag`, `getprevious().text`, `getnext().tag` and `getnext().text` to return the previous and next tags and texts from the node in question, but this will only return the adjacent elements, rather than all the siblings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all children of specific node in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716073/get-all-children-of-specific-node-in-python)

Comment: Is XPath not "straightforward"?

Comment: @RamonMedeiros this works fine when it gets the children, but not for siblings (as far as I've tried). But combining it with the answer below may work.

Comment: @mzjn I'd rather not use XPath in all honesty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```py
from io import StringIO
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

data = """<ParentOne>
   <SiblingOneA>This is Sibling One A</SiblingOneA>
   <SiblingTwoA>
      <ChildOneA>Value of child one A</ChildOneA>
      <ChildTwoA>Value of child two A</ChildTwoA>
      <ChildThreeA>Value of child three A</ChildThreeA>
      <ChildFourA>Value of child four A</ChildFourA>
   </SiblingTwoA>
</ParentOne>"""

tree = ET.parse(StringIO(data))
root = tree.getroot()
sibling_two = root.find('SiblingTwoA')
for children in sibling_two:
    print(f'{children.tag} = {children.text}')
```

---

Gives the **output**:

```
ChildOneA : Value of child one A
ChildTwoA : Value of child two A
ChildThreeA : Value of child three A
ChildFourA : Value of child four A
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a go and see if it works given my code (as this is only a snippet). Just out of curiosity, as this checks for all children from the parent, it will return the node in question as well (i.e. ChildThreeA). Is there any more explicit way of return all siblings so that ChildThreeA is not returned? I can obviously disregard it so it's not a big deal, but I'm just curious to know.